# Selenium + ChromeDriver

Tags: javascript, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta para realizar o login num site, porém estou com um problema.

Quando eu faço o procedimento manual(abrindo navegador, acessando site, digitando usuário/senha e realizando o login), a próxima é carregada sem abrir outra aba ou outra página, mas quando eu realizo via IDE, ao realizar o login, o navegador entende que tem que abrir outra página.

Alguém saberia como resolver esse problema? Pois já procurei a respeito e nada encontrei.

Answer (score 1):

consegui resolver (após um intervenção divina) o problema.

Após eu realizar o login no site, eu coloco o seguinte código:

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

Obrigado.